How to continue the fluid after the end of the curve guide?
I'm working on a fluid simulation in which the fluid flows along a curve guide.
When the fluid reaches the end of the curve, I want it to continue in the same direction and splash into the bowl.

However, what happens now is that it stops flowing at the end of the curve guide and starts to build up there.

How should I get the desired effect? If I reduce the strength of the curve guide at the end, the fluid along the curve will not hold its shape, spreading out therefore ruining it.
If this is not possible through Blender's Mantaflow, I'm open to answers using FLIP Fluids.
I've attached the .blend here.

You can add a falloff max distance to the bezier curve, so it stops affecting the fluit when it reaches far from the curve (or you can reduce the strength at the end as you said - I would like to know how if you would).

Then you can add a "wind" force with a plane shape at the end of the curve, pointing towards the bowl (my example was lazy and I didn't adjust it perfectly - taking too much time to simulate)
Control de falloff of this wind to act on a "tube" and only near the end of the curve.

When the fluid reaches the tube it accelerates towards the bowl and colides.
The rest is adjusting the size, direction, the "flow", etc to create the desired effect.

Thanks, it works - I had an idea this might be the solution (this is what I meant by reducing the strength at the end) however I just didn't try it out :)
